# Get Network Bandwidth and write the data using subprocess (Python : v3.8.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, terminal, subprocess

Iam trying to monitor the network bandwidth using any command, run it using subprocess and then load the data in json format for my API.
I currently came across 3 terminal commands.
1- vnstat
2- fast
3- nload

Fast is better in providing the real time network bandwidth. But nload also give real time data in a clear manner. How do i get the data in either of the cases if iam using subprocess so that my API doesnt end up facing a request timeout error.??

Comment: Not sure what your question is about, most subprocess functions take a timeout parameter (per default disabled): https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 Hello. I figured out an approach to implement what i had meant. My question might not have been clear enough. But maybe my answer could explain what exactly i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was basically trying to achieve the output of the subprocess for a command and write it in json format.

```
cmd=['vnstat']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
p.stdout.close()
status = p.returncode
if status is None:
    network_bandwidth = {"network_bandwidth": {}}
    for line in output.splitlines():
        each_line = line.split()
        network_bandwidth["network_bandwidth"] = {"key":"Here i did the processing part where i extracted the received and transmitted data and prepared my json response"}
else:
    logger.error("Error in executing the command '{}'".format(cmd))
return network_bandwidth
```